# Multiple warnings using RealmSwift 3.1.1 in Xcode 9

Tags: realm, swift4, xcode9

I get 23 compiler warnings after adding the above versioned RealmSwift CocoaPod to any of my Xcode 9.2 projects (see screenshot).

Cocoapods versions installed (1.4.0, 1.3.1)
RealmSwift version 3.1.1

[image]

The specific message reads:

> /Users/myname/Repos/iOS Projects/My
>   Projects/TestRealmPods/Pods/Realm/Realm/RLMArray.mm:256:10: Block
>   implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this
>   is intended behaviour

The warnings only appear if I try to Build / Run the project.
The warnings relate to the RLMArray.mm & RLMManagedArray.mm classes only.

I have tried updating both CocoaPods & Realm versions from previous versions, but get the same warnings in both cases.

Any help provided is much appreciated.

Comment: Same here, but I don't think this is some issue, just annoying. They will probably fix this in next release, it should just be a matter of putting self instead of just calling those methods or vars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning happens because, CocoaPods is moving to enable CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF by
default. I think, this warning will be fixed in next Realm releases. But as temporary solution you can add this code to your Podfile file to silence a warnings.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF'] = false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Emmett, this silenced the warnings I was getting.